# FullCalendar events with ColdFusion

Tags: json, coldfusion

I am trying to load events from my database into FullCalendar using ColdFusion here is what I have so far.

**JavaScript:**

```
events: {
            url: 'load-calendar.cfm',
            type: 'GET',
            error: function() {
                alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
            }
        }
```

**ColdFusion:**

```
<cffunction name="getMyData" output="false" access="remote" returntype="any" returnformat="JSON">

    <cfargument name="filter" type="string" required="no" default="">

    <cfset var getEvents = "">
    <cfset var row = "">
    <cfset var result = "">

    <cfquery name="getCalendar" datasource="datasource">
       SELECT * FROM Calendar
       WHERE userID = '#session.user.userID#'
    </cfquery>

    <cfset result = []>
    <cfloop query="getCalendar">
        <cfset row = {}>
        <cfset row["id"] = id>
        <cfset row["title"] = title>
        <cfset row["start"] =  dateScheduledFor>
        <cfset row["allDay"] = "true">

        <cfset arrayAppend(result, row)>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn serializeJSON(result)>

</cffunction>
```

Nothing displays in my calendar. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't forget to use `<cfqueryparam>`

Comment: In your JS example, you specify the URL as `load-calendar.cfm`, however, you posted code from a function named `getMyData` with no explanation of how the former uses the latter.